# 演じる for performing in tv/movies/anime

Tags: verbs, english-to-japanese

I know the verb 演じる is used for performing on stage, but can it be used for tv shows/movies/anime as well? For example, can I say

3月のライオンというTVアニメで花澤香菜さんは演じました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 演じる can be used for tv shows, movies, anime as well, but...

> 3月のライオンというTVアニメで花澤香菜さんは演じました。

If I heard this, I would want to ask 「何の役を」?

You can use 演じる this way (演じる is a transitive verb):

> ［tv show/movie/anime etc.］で［actor］さんは［role］(役/の役)を演じました。

e.g.

> 「3月のライオンというTVアニメで花澤香菜さんは川本ひなた(の)役を演じました。」
> 「ハリソン・フォードさんはスター・ウォーズでハン・ソロを演じました。」

If you don't mention the role, you can use the verb 出演する (to appear), like this (出演する is an intransitive verb):

> 「花澤香菜さんは3月のライオンというTVアニメに出演しました。」

(「花澤香菜さんは3月のライオンというTVアニメに川本ひなた役で出演しました。」 would also work.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to talk about someone starring in a show/play/game without specifying the role, you can use 出演{しゅつえん}する.

So your sentence would look like

> 花澤香菜さんは3月のライオンというTVアニメに出演しました。